# Comma-delimited and dash-delimited text fields in MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a Razor form in our web app. During a meeting with the clients, we learned that one of the fields in this form should accept input that is:

- A list of comma-delimited numbers
- including ranges of numbers expressed using dashes

For example, the end-users might enter `45,50-53,65` to represent the list of numbers 45, 50, 51, 52, 53, 65. I'm assuming that the textbox might contain arbitrary whitespace as well that should be ignored (so `45, 50-53, 65` would represent the same information).

How would I set up such a text box in MVC 4 using Razor? In particular,

1. How would I create the text box in my Razor view?
2. How would I represent the information in the text box in my model?
3. How would I data-bind the text box to the model?
4. How would I set up validation for the text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I would just create a normal textbox -- you're asking for a string of numbers
2. You could have the form value as a string, and then another property that is the parsed version of the string, int[].
3. Since it is a string, it can be posted as a string.
4. Use a regular expression for the validator.

For 2, you could do something like this in your model:

```
public string Numbers { get; set; }
public int[] ParsedNumbers
{
    get
    {
        Func<int[], int[]> arrayToRange = (range) =>
        {
            if (range.Length == 1) return range;
            int[] ret = new int[range[1] - range[0] + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < ret.Length; i++)
            {
                ret[i] = i + range[0];
            }
            return ret;
        };

        return this.Numbers
                    .Replace(" ", "")
                    .Split(',')
                    .SelectMany(n => arrayToRange(n.Split('-')
                        .Select(n2 => int.Parse(n2)).ToArray())).ToArray();
    }
}
```

For 4, you could use this RegEx:

```
^(\d(\-\d)?(, ?)?)*$
```